# How can I delete images uploaded to TinyGrab?

Tags: delete, screenshot

How can I delete images uploaded to [TinyGrab](http://tinygrab.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [TinyGrab FAQ](http://tinygrab.com/questionsPremium.):

> **Q. How can I delete a grab from the
>   TinyGrab server?**
>
> Visit the TinyGrab
>   online control panel at
>   http://tinygrab.com/go/panel to delete
>   an image that you've uploaded to
>   TinyGrab. This is a Premium service
>   only. Only under special / certain
>   circumstances will we respond to
>   support requests to delete images from
>   our service. Free TinyGrab accounts
>   are intended as a trial and not to be
>   used as a replacement to TinyGrab
>   Premium.

You can [submit a support ticket](http://help.tinygrab.com/anonymous_requests/new) requesting them to remove a specific screenshot, but they will only do so under special circumstances. I've done this before, and they removed it pretty quickly.